# List<string> serialize to string and not to json array with json.net

Tags: arrays, serialization, json.net

I'm trying to serialize a list of roles within a token returned to an angular client.

The code in c# is:

```
List<Claim> roles = oAuthIdentity.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Role).ToList();
var serialRoles = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(roles.Select(x => x.Value));
AuthenticationProperties properties = CreateProperties(user.UserName, serialRoles);
```

CreateProperties method:

```
    public static AuthenticationProperties CreateProperties(string userName, string roles)
    {
        IDictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "userName", userName },
            { "roles", roles }
        };
        return new AuthenticationProperties(data);
    }
```

My problem is I'm trying to generate something like:

```
{
....
"roles": ["Administrator","Sales"],
....
}
```

but I'm receiving roles as a string and not an array:

```
{
....
"roles":"[\"Administrator\",\"Sales\"]",
....
}
```

Any idea?
Regards

Comment: Are you serializing `AuthenticationProperties` again by any chance?

Comment: How are you generating your final JSON?  What object are you serializing?

Comment: It's not a problem with any other part of the code.It's not a problem with token delivery because the problem appear in the SerializeObject call [var serialRoles = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(roles.Select(x => x.Value));]. Could be some option from json.net? It's flattening json.net the array?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem.
I'm not sure if this is the right answer.

It's solved with a JSON.parse() in the client. Then the json from the string is well formatted.
Regards